# Is this statement about the following condition correct?

Tags: actionscript-3

Look at this code:

```
var a:Number = 1;
var b:String = "hello";

if (a == 1 && b == "goodbye") {
    trace("options a and b");
}
```

The book I am reading says: **"In this example, the test would evaluate to true, because one of the two conditions (the first) is true. As a result, “option a or b” would be traced."**

Isn't the above statement incorrect? this if statement to me reads as "if a is 1 and b is goodbye THEN output it"

Comment: yes is wrong should be || instead of &&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct and the book you are reading is wrong. As Eric comments it should be an || in the code, which is indicated by the text that the result should be "option a **or** b" (the code is wrong here as well...).

/AZ

Answer (score 1):

The **and**(&&) operator is used to test if both operands are true, e.g:

```
if(1 < 2 &&  2 < 3)
{
    trace("will trace");
}
```

which is the equivalent to:

```
if(1 < 2)
{
    if(2 < 3)
    {
        trace("will trace");
    }
}
```

The **or**(||) operator is used to test if either(or both) operands are true, e.g:

```
if(1 < 2 || 2 < 3)
{
    trace("will trace");
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if(1 < 2)
{
    trace("will trace");
}
else if(2 < 3)
{
    trace("will trace");
}
```

Keep in mind not to mistake the **and**(&&) and **or**(!!) operators with the bitwise **AND**(&) and **OR**(|) operators.

Answer (score 0):

you are correct, the book has a typo (i hope) :-)

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: thanks, it was an answer to the question. this is a comment as well.